# React Native: Redirecting BankId App back to App on iOS not working

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am developing an application on React Native that uses BankId and I am using Linking to automatically open the BankId and redirect back to the app after the user is signed there.
Url Scheme saved on both Android and iOS is: com.company.myappname
This is the part of the code that opens the BankId App based on the URL

```
const bankIdAppUrl = https://app.bankid.com/?autostarttoken=[valueOfToken]&redirect=com.company.myappname://
Linking.openURL(bankIdAppUrl)
```

When this code is run the BankId is opened successfully on both devices Android and iOS and when the verification is done correctly. When I go back on Android is works properly and continue the api call that was waiting for the BankId Verification to return a response.

On the other side on iOS is gives this error

```
nw_read_request_report [C13] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
 Connection 14: received failure notification
[connection] nw_write_request_report [C14] Send failed with error "Socket is not connected"
Task <A4B25611-8258-4AFD-AA2A-CEF3B87700F9>.<5> HTTP load failed, 170/0 bytes (error code: -1005 [1:53])
Task <A4B25611-8258-4AFD-AA2A-CEF3B87700F9>.<5> finished with error [-1005] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, NSUnderlyingError=0x2814ca430 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <A4B25611-8258-4AFD-AA2A-CEF3B87700F9>.<5>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <A4B25611-8258-4AFD-AA2A-CEF3B87700F9>.<5>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=endpoint, NSErrorFailingURLKey=endpoint, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

I did some research and it says that iOS cancel the api if you move on another app and that why the api fails directly and I need to use libraries to handle it on the background. I came across react-native-background-fetch which can handle it back I cannot make it work.

Thank you everyone in advance for your time.